# Tailwind CSS couldn't work by status string

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am thinking of changing the colors in Tailwind depending on the status, but some of the colors change, but not others.

Is there a best practice?

```
<span>{statusColor(status)}</span>


export const statusColor = (status: string) => {
  if (status === "canceled") {
    return "bg-red-100 text-red-500"
  } else if (pendingStatuses.includes(status)) {
    return "bg-yellow-100 text-yellow-500"
  } else if (approvedStatuses.includes(status)) {
    return "bg-emerald-100 text-emerald-500"
  } else {
    return "bg-gray-100 text-gray-500"
  }
}
```

Comment: tailwind will not scan your JS files for classes to include, the working ones must exist in your HTML so they are copied already, to test just add the missing colours to a HTML element

Comment: Could you show `pendingStatuses` or `approvedStatuses`?

Answer (score 0):

Just return the statusColor() in the class of span as follows

```
<span className={statusColor(status)} > My Status </span>


export const statusColor = (status: string) => {
  if (status === "canceled") {
    return "bg-red-100 text-red-500"
  } else if (pendingStatuses.includes(status)) {
    return "bg-yellow-100 text-yellow-500"
  } else if (approvedStatuses.includes(status)) {
    return "bg-emerald-100 text-emerald-500"
  } else {
    return "bg-gray-100 text-gray-500"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using clsx is the best practice in react js. you can see more detail in their docs.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

```
  className={clsx(
        status === "canceled" ? 'bg-red-100 text-red-500':pendingStatuses.includes(status)) ?
          "bg-yellow-100 text-yellow-500":pendingStatuses.includes(status)) ? "bg-yellow-100 text-yellow-500":"bg-gray-100 text-gray-500",
      )}
```